# The biggest binomial coefficient in $(n+\frac 1n)^n$ if the product of the fourth member in the expansion and the fourth from back member is 14400

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm stuck on this one. I am not expected to know how to solve cubic equations so this gets even more confusing, as i get $\binom n 3 = 120$. So I can't even calculate $n$.

Is there a way to go around solving the cubic equation?

Comment: You can solve $\binom{n}{3} = 120$ by trial and error, no theory needed.

Comment: $n(n-1)(n-2)=6\times 120$ so take the cube root of $720$ to get an estimate. Do you know a cube near $720$?

Comment: There do exist ways of solving cubic equations explicitly (as well as solving quartics).  It is of interest to note that the quintic however is not always solvable (one of the big results from Galois Theory).  The cubic can be solved via [Cardano's Formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula)

Comment: Very true, Daniel, it seems I cop out too early on most of these questions. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!} = 120 \implies (n-1)^3-(n-1) = 720 \implies (n-1)^3 > 720$$
Hence, $n > 1+\sqrt[3]{720}$. By a same argument $(n-2)^3 < 720$, which implies that $n < 2+\sqrt[3]{720}$. It is not that hard to approximate $\sqrt[3]{720}$, since $9^3 = 729$. This means $9<n<11$. Hence, the only possible integer is $10$, which indeed satisfied $\dbinom{10}3 = 720$.